# Assign Error bars for y-intercept

Tags: probability-or-statistics, mathematical-optimization, fitting, data

I have some data (x,y) with error bars in y direction:

```
  {{{1/10, 4.92997}, ErrorBar[0.00875039]}, {{1/20, 4.90374}, 
  ErrorBar[0.00912412]}, {{1/25, 4.89318}, 
  ErrorBar[0.00707122]}, {{1/30, 4.89534}, 
  ErrorBar[0.00870608]}, {{1/40, 4.87807}, 
  ErrorBar[0.00829155]}, {{1/50, 4.84442}, 
  ErrorBar[0.0226886]}, {{1/100, 4.83867}, ErrorBar[0.0973819]}}
```

Now I am trying to find a linear fit to the data, and I want the y-intercept of this linear fit (when x=0). How do I get the uncertainty (error bar) for the y-intercept due to those error bars in the data?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Correction:  I've corrected the description of the second model to match what *Mathematica* actually does as opposed to what I wanted to believe it did.**

Use the `Weights` option with the inverse of the square of the errors:

```
data = {{{1/10, 4.92997}, ErrorBar[0.00875039]}, {{1/20, 4.90374}, ErrorBar[0.00912412]},
   {{1/25, 4.89318}, ErrorBar[0.00707122]}, {{1/30, 4.89534}, ErrorBar[0.00870608]},
   {{1/40, 4.87807}, ErrorBar[0.00829155]}, {{1/50, 4.84442}, ErrorBar[0.0226886]},
   {{1/100, 4.83867}, ErrorBar[0.0973819]}};
error = data[[All, 2]] /. ErrorBar[x_] -> x;
t = Table[{data[[i, 1, 1]], Around[data[[i, 1, 2]], error[[i]]]}, {i, Length[error]}];
lmf = LinearModelFit[data[[All, 1]], x, x, Weights -> 1/error^2];
lmf["ParameterTable"]
Show[ListPlot[t], Plot[{lmf["MeanPredictionBands"], lmf[x]}, {x, 0, 0.1}]]
```

[image: Parameter estimates]

[image: Data with error bars and prediction with mean confidence band]

***Appendix:  Why not use `VarianceEstimatorFunction` ?***

Consider 3 linear models with slightly different error structures:

$$y_i=a+b x_i+σϵ_i$$
$$y_i=a+b x_i+w_i \sigma \epsilon_i$$
$$y_i=a+b x_i+w_i \epsilon_i$$

where $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n$ are the observations, $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ and $w_1,w_2,\ldots w_n$ are known constants, $a$, $b$, and $σ$ are parameters to be estimated, and $ϵ_i \sim N(0,1)$.

The first model has errors ($σϵ_i$) with the same distribution for all observations.  The second model has the standard deviation of the random error proportional to the weights.  The third model has the random error standard deviation being exactly the associated weight (i.e., the same structure as the second model but with $\sigma=1$).

While I would argue that there are few instances where the third model is appropriate, that model can be appropriate when justified.  (Also, weights are most of the time estimated from some previous data collection process rather than really being known but I’ll suspend disbelief about that for this discussion.)  It would be desirable for *Mathematica* to offer the option of two (or more) sources of random error (measurement error and lack-of-fit error) but that is not currently directly available.

To estimate the coefficients in the 3 models, Mathematica would use 3 different formulations of LinearModelFit:

```
lmf1=LinearModelFit[data,x,x]
lmf2=LinearModelFit[data,x,x,Weights->1/error^2]
lmf3=LinearModelFit[data,x,x,Weights->1/error^2,VarianceEstimatorFunction->(1&)]
```

Here are the parameter estimates for the 3 models:

[image: First model parameter table]

[image: Second model parameter table]

[image: Third model parameter table]

The moral of the story is that what options to use with `LinearModelFit` and `NonlinearModelFit` depends on what error structure is reasonable.
So the use of the option `VarianceEstimatorFunction` implies a specific type of error structure.  Does the OP know that there is only measurement error and that the weights are known precisely?  I would find that hard to believe so I wouldn’t use `VarianceEstimatorFunction -> (1)&` in this case.

While knowing what error structure is appropriate prior to collecting the data is preferred, is there a way to use the data to suggest which error structure is better?  (Not "best" but “better” in a relative sense).  The answer is Yes.  The model with the smallest AIC (or AICc) value should usually be chosen (unless maybe the difference in AIC values is less than 1 or 2 and then take the one that is either less complicated or matches the measurement process).

For this data the second model fits best by a small amount:

```
lmf1["AICc"]
(* -25.423 *)
lmf2["AICc"]
(* -30.1466 *)
lmf3["AICc"]
(* -29.4193 *)
```

The AICc values are close between the second and third models so it is not impossible that the third model is inappropriate in this case.  However, I would still argue that in practice one should always consider the second model.

The estimated variance for the second model is less than 1 which suggests that the estimated weights might be a bit too large (which is counter to what I think usually happens):

lmf2["EstimatedVariance"]
(* 0.758505 *)
lmf3["EstimatedVariance"]
(* 1 *)

In short, fitting a linear model includes both the "fixed" (expected value) portion *and* the random structure and just because one "knows" the precision of the measurement that doesn't mean that there aren't other sources of error (especially that the weights are known exactly).  More flexibility with error structures would be a great addition to *Mathematica*.

Comment: I think you need the option `VarianceEstimatorFunction->(1&)` to get the scale of the errors right. See the "Details and Options" of the documentation.

Comment: My current Mathematica version does not support Around[], do you know any replacement for it?

Comment: @Roman.  Absolutely not (in almost all cases of data supplied to this forum).  By using `VarianceEstimatorFunction->(1/&)`, `LinearModelFit` assumes that the only variability is associated with the measurements and there is no additional lack-of-fit variability about the linear function.  To be convincing of that try `error = 0.00001 {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};`.  One will get ridiculously small standard errors for the coefficients.  If *Mathematica* would add the ability to have multiple levels of errors (mixed models), then that would be closer to being current in software ability of SAS and R.

Comment: @lol You'll then need to execute `Needs["ErrorBarPlots\`"]` followed by `Show[ErrorListPlot[data], 
 Plot[{lmf["MeanPredictionBands"], lmf[x]}, {x, 0, 0.1}], 
 PlotRange -> All]`.

Comment: @JimB Quoting from [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VarianceEstimatorFunction.html): "With `VarianceEstimatorFunction->(1&)` and `Weights->{1/Δy1^2,1/Δy2^2,…}`, `Δyi` is treated as the known uncertainty of measurement `yi` and parameter standard errors are effectively computed only from the weights." As an example, `LinearModelFit[{0,0,0,0,0}, 1, x, Weights -> {1,1,1,1,1}, VarianceEstimatorFunction -> (1 &)]["ParameterTable"]` gives the expected standard error of $1/\sqrt{5}$ for the fit coefficient; leaving out the `VarianceEstimatorFunction` does not.

Comment: @Roman I'll cook up an example to explain what I mean and why I believe the documentation is not incorrect as to what it says but misleading to almost everybody.  I'm hoping I'm right but I'd prefer to give the correct advice if it turns out I'm wrong.

Comment: @Roman I've added in a discussion about the need to consider an appropriate error structure.  I think your example is a bit pathological because it gives $1/\sqrt{5}$ no matter what 5 data points are given.  Yes, the standard error for the mean is that value but when one knows the variance but no sample would result in `{0,0,0,0,0}`.  Leaving out `VarianceEstimatorFunction` does not give the known answer for `{0,0,0,0,0}` because there is no sample variability to allow one to estimate the variance. However, It does work for a real random sample no matter what the true variance happens to be.

Comment: @Roman I messed up with the description of the error structure of the second model.  I believe I've now fixed that.

Comment: @JimB Hello, I struggle understanding how Weights may be used to take into account the experimental error of the individual data points. So, let's say I have same yet non-zero error for all of the points. That would mean, that following the suggested route, I will have to use a list of same numbers for weights. But then, this means that all points have same weight, which doesn't depend (i.e. doesn't take into account) the value of the error.. Or, did I miss something?

Comment: @Bulat You didn't miss anything.  Suppose there is an error variance about the curve ($\sigma^2$) and an identical error variance associated with each measurement ($\tau^2$).  Then what you end up estimating is $\sigma^2+\tau^2$ and you can't get separate estimates for each variance component.  But the measurement error is really being taken into account.