# What is the best way to use errors in mathematica M12?

Tags: plotting, fitting, list-manipulation, around

Since `ErrorListPlot` has been superseded by new functionality in `ListPlot` for Mathematica 12.0, what is the best way to handle errors efficiently? Previously I would simply format my data in a table as

```
    Data = 
    Table[
            Stuf to calculate values and errors
            {{xValue, yValue, yError}},
            {i, 1, Stop}
         ]
```

Which made it easy to stick into `ErrorListPlot` or use in a fit as

```
NonlinearModel[Data[[1;;,{1, 2}]], Function, Weights->1/Data[[1;;,3]]^2 ]
```

Now it seems you have to use `Around[yValue, yError]`

```
        Data = 
        Table[
                Stuf to calculate values and errors
                {{xValue, Around[yValue, yError]}},
                {i, 1, Stop}
             ]
```

Which works fine in `ListPlot` and I can fit data with it, as in it produces a fit result, but I can't figure out how to use `Weights` with `Around` and I can't plot the result of the fit in the usual way. Can anyone recommend an efficient way to format data in line with the new updates?

Comment: maybe `NonlinearModelFit[data /. a_Around:>a["Value"], model, parameters, vars, Weights->(1/(data[[All,2]] /. a_Around:>a["Uncertainty"])^2)]`?

Comment: That'll do it! Thanks!

Comment: QuantumPenguin, posted the comment as an answer.

Comment: Don't forget to use "MeanPredictionBands" after fitting which gives you the result of the fit with the measurement errors.  That is the "error" display that would be of most interest to the user of your analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the advice JimB.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can extract the properties `"Value"` and `"Uncertainty"` from `Around` objects:

```
NonlinearModelFit[data /. a_Around :> a["Value"], 
 model, parameters, vars, 
 Weights -> (1/(data[[All,2]] /. a_Around :> a["Uncertainty"])^2)]
```

Comment: Thanks for this nice answer, it's poorly documented on how to use errors in version 12 so this is a great help.

Comment: Don't forget to set the [`VarianceEstimatorFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VarianceEstimatorFunction.html) appropriately. My favorite is `VarianceEstimatorFunction->(1&)` but [opinions differ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/203209/26598).